# on boot scripts in mac osx?

Tags: linux, macos

Are there any equivalent scripts run on boot on mac osx (`/etc/rc.d` etc.)?

such as we can found in linux:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036/files-and-scripts-that-execute-on-boot

Comment: please take a look at this superuser entry: http://superuser.com/questions/245713/whats-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-script-run-at-boot-time-in-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally handled by `launchd`. Exactly how you do it (LaunchAgent vs LaunchDaemon) depends on whether you want it to be run as a system process or a user process. See [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-BBCBHBFB) for details.